# Reporting both Kendall's tau and Goodman's Gamma, does it make sense?

Tags: correlation, nonparametric, spearman-rho, reporting, kendall-tau

In a data analysis, does it make sense to report both Kendall's tau and Goodman's Gamma? I guess not, since tau looks like a standardized form of Gamma. Or does it add some explanation?

Comment: If the data have no ties, gamma = tau. If the data have ties, you should think what to do with them - leave out? ignore? take into account - how? Hence you arrive at gamma or tau-a, tau-b, tau-c, etc. Please search this site for `Gamma`, `Kendall`.

Comment: Make sure you happen across [ttnphns' answer to a related question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/18136/32036) in your search!