# Am I using Goodman-Kruskal gamma or Somers D or Kendall tau correctly and what do they mean?

Tags: r, goodness-of-fit, multinomial-distribution, somers-d, goodman-kruskal-gamma

I am seemingly blindly following this [publication](http://www.cfc.umt.edu/grizzlybearrecovery/pdfs/Schwartz%20et%20al.%202006e.pdf) that has done work very similar to what I need to accomplish (page 18-21).  My analysis is a multinomial logistic regression where I have 3 possible outcomes 0, 1, or 2 offspring produced.  In the publication, they have recommended a Hosmer-Lemshow and a Persons test for goodness-of-fit.  I have only figured out how to do the Hosmer-Lemshow test and my results are not so good (i.e. P-val is 0.00002).  I have no idea how to do the Pearsons test (suggestions are appreciated).

The paper I am following, of course their tests are "good" for model fit (page 21).  But they then go onto suggest that Somers D, the Goodman-Kruskala gamma and the Kendall's tau-a all indicate that their models are a good fit.  But the paper does not report any of the values for these indices or how they calculated them.

I have just found a package `ryouready` that runs all of these tests.  However, I have been having difficulties finding any help explaining what the values mean, let alone knowing if I have input my variables correctly.

My response variable is number of offspring, most of my explanatory variables are continuous like age or risk.  Do I need to calculate the mean of each explanatory variable within each response variable (get the mean risk for 1 offspring, mean risk for 2 offspring etc...)and then compare those? It also seems that these tests are for 2x2 tables.  If I am just looking at risk, my table would be a 1x3.  However, my complete model will have 4 variables (age, risk, bp, and #offspring year before).

As you can likely tell, I am in the dark here on where to start. I would appreciate suggested readings, pdf lectures or videos of lectures would even be better!

EDIT/UPDATE:
I have run the tests over my counts - I have 2 time periods (before/after) and then the count of offspring in each class (0,1,2).  I do not know how to interpret the values - what is "good".  What should I be looking for?  Any source that explains these values would be nice to see.

```
Kendall's (and Stuart's) Tau statistics
    Tau-b: 0.143
    Tau-c: 0.130
Somers' d:
    Columns dependent: 0.151 
    Rows dependent: 0.136 
    Symmetric: 0.143 
Goodman-Kruskal Gamma: 0.312 
Warning message:
In formatC(x, digits, format = "f") : class of 'x' was discarded
```

Comment: Start please with formulas of these related statistics http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/18136/3277.