# interpretation of Goodman Kruskal Gamma

Tags: categorical-data, goodman-kruskal-gamma

Value of Goodman-Kruskal Gamma = 1 or -1 means that X and Y are monotonic but not strictly so i.e., $X_1  < X_2$ implies $Y_1 \leq Y_2 $.
Can someone please explain this to me with an example?

Comment: You can see from the [formula of Gamma](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/18136/3277) that pairs of cases 1 and 2 where X1=X2 or Y1=Y2 - they are called "ties" - are simply ignored by Gamma. This is why Gamma can attain 1 or -1 in the face of their presence.