# What does spearman being higher than tau imply?

Tags: correlation, spearman-rho, kendall-tau

If Kendall's tau is lower than Spearman, what does it mean?

Comment: Nothing, cf. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18112/how-do-the-goodman-kruskal-gamma-and-the-kendall-tau-or-spearman-rho-correlation/18136#18136

Comment: [It's very common](http://i.stack.imgur.com/inYqE.png)