# What should the diagonal values be in a correlation matrix with Stuart–Kendall Tau-c?

Tags: r, correlation, kendall-tau

I'm trying to calculate a correlation matrix for ordinal variables in R. [Kendall rank correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient), seems a good option, as it *"is a statistic used to measure the **ordinal association** between two measured quantities"* (emphasis added).

Since I have variables with a different number of ordinal levels, I'm planning to use Stuart-Kendall Tau-c for accounting for ties when calculating the coefficient: *"Tau-c (also called Stuart-Kendall Tau-c) is more suitable than Tau-b for the analysis of data based on non-square (i.e. rectangular) contingency tables."*

The R package [`DescTools`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DescTools/versions/0.99.46) has a function `StuartTauC` which calculates *"Stuart's Tau-c statistic, a measure of association for ordinal factors in a two-way table."*

As an example, I will use three ordinal variables from the `diamonds` dataset in [`ggplot2`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/):

```
# Import "diamonds" dataset from ggplot2
library( ggplot2 )

head( diamonds[2:4] )

# A tibble: 6 x 3
#   cut       color clarity
#   <ord>     <ord> <ord>  
# 1 Ideal     E     SI2    
# 2 Premium   E     SI1    
# 3 Good      E     VS1    
# 4 Premium   I     VS2    
# 5 Good      J     SI2    
# 6 Very Good J     VVS2
```

My implementation in R is as follows (I'm open to better implementations for calculating the matrix):

```
library( DescTools )

df <- diamonds[2:4]

cor_matrix <- matrix(
    nrow = ncol( df ),
    ncol = ncol( df )
)
rownames( cor_matrix ) <- names( df )
colnames( cor_matrix ) <- names( df )

for( row in 1:ncol( df ) ){
    for( col in 1:ncol( df ) ){
        cor_matrix[row, col] <- StuartTauC( df[[row]], df[[col]] )
    }
}

cor_matrix

# Result:
#
#                 cut       color   clarity
# cut      0.89458402 -0.01356334 0.1464609
# color   -0.01356334  0.97953628 0.0232527
# clarity  0.14646089  0.02325270 0.9405563
```

My question is, shouldn't the diagonal values be 1, or is this a feature of the Tau-C statistic (or the function `StuartTauC`)?

Comment: Please check footnotes in https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/18136/3277

Comment: I won't try to dig into the math behind the statistic, but returning a value value less than 1 even when correlating a variable with itself appears to have something to do with having an unequal number of observations in each level.  Consider A correlated with A and B correlated with B. `A = factor(c("Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "High")); B = factor(c("Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "High")); StuartTauC(A, A); StuartTauC(B, B)`

Comment: Thank you @ttnphns! If you could add the footnote on Tau-c as an answer here (maybe with an easy-to-understand refererence?), I will accept it.

Comment: Thanks also @SalMangiafico. I'll take a look at papers and textbooks describing Tau-c.

Comment: I've done some more reading. In Stuarts original paper (1953, doi:10.2307/2333101), when deriving tau-c, he concludes that "tc can sometimes attain, and for large n can generally almost attain, +-1." What still puzzles me is that the "diamonds" dataset has an n of 53940 which I consider rather large. Still, the diagonal values of the correlation matrix are quite far from 1 (especially for "cut").